# Vue, firebase database return the empty array

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vuejs2

I am trying to retrieve the data from firebase database.

And I can connect to firebase auth and check **currentUser** data, it's fine.
But I can't retrieve the data from firebase database, it just return the empty array.

firebase version = 5.0.4
vue version = 2.5.16

**The database structure**

```
users/     
--------uId/        
--------------name    
--------------email
```

---

**Vue Js folder structure**

```
App.vue    
firebase.js    
main.js     
components /     
------------ Home.vue
```

---

**firebase.js**

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
require("firebase/auth");     
require("firebase/database");

var config = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    databaseURL: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "..."
};
firebase.initializeApp(config)
export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const db = firebase.database()
```

**Home.vue**

```
<script>
import {db} from './../firebase';
import {auth} from './../firebase';
var usersRef = db.ref('users');

export default {
    name: "Home",
    components: {
        add_new
    },
    data(){
        return {}
    },
    mounted: function(){
        console.log(usersRef);
        var userId = auth.currentUser.uid;
        return db.ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function (childData) {
                console.log(childData.val())
            })
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

---

Here, Vue app works correctly,
 only the firebase.database ( **usersRef** ) returns the empty array.

This is the screenshot of **console.log(usersRef)** result
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/NH7gh.png

Comment: You are sure that `userId` has the right value? Because nowhere in your code appears the login part. If you do `console.log(userId)` do you get the correct value?

Comment: Yes I got the correct value such as "jzeagloTU8Qjpfxo....", And I open the database for both **read and write**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First instead of using multiple import statements, why not

```
import {auth, db} from './../firebase';
```

And try to change

```
snapshot.forEach(function (childData) {
   console.log(childData.val())
})
```

to `snapshot.val()`

```
var userId = auth.currentUser.uid;
return db.ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
   console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Comment: Sorry @FewFlyBy, I tried the same as your answer like `console.log(snapshot.val());` , but it returns **null**.

Comment: do you get the value of userId  when you console log it?

Comment: Thanks @FewFlyBy, it was my mistakes, I logged in with a wrong user that has no data.